# mule esb web service consumer SOAP - error: Prefix not specified

Tags: soap, mule, consumer

I try to reproduce the flow "listInventory" of the example project "tshirt-service-consumer" of Mule ESB 3.5.0 Community Runtime with my own web service SOAP. But when I run the project I have an error in my console

```
WARN  2014-07-20 22:16:21,541 [main] org.mule.module.ws.consumer.RequestBodyGenerator: Unable to check if the operation requires input parameters, the payload will be used as SOAP body
org.mule.common.metadata.MetaDataGenerationException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Prefix not specified
    at org.mule.common.metadata.XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.createFields(XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.java:104)
    at org.mule.common.metadata.DefaultXmlMetaDataModel.<init>(DefaultXmlMetaDataModel.java:46)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.RequestBodyGenerator.generateRequestBody(RequestBodyGenerator.java:79)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.parseWsdl(WSConsumer.java:333)
    at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer.initialise(WSConsumer.java:87)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:80)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:314)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:215)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:109)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:103)
    at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:78)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:174)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:274)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:294)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:261)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:110)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:287)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:148)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:130)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Prefix not specified
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3459)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parse(Locale.java:706)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:690)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:677)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:208)
    at org.mule.common.metadata.XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.findRootElement(XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.java:246)
    at org.mule.common.metadata.XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.createFields(XmlMetaDataFieldFactory.java:95)
    ... 53 more
```

When I call my web service with another client soap, I have no problem.

**wsdl :**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.3 (tags/2.3-7528; 2013-04-29T19:34:10+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.8 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.3 (tags/2.3-7528; 2013-04-29T19:34:10+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.8 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://xml.heg-arc.ch/srv/CustomerService/1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://xml.heg-arc.ch/srv/CustomerService/1.0" name="CustomerService">
<import namespace="http://xml.he-arc.ch/srv/CustomerService/1.0" location="http://localhost:8080/TB-Service2/CustomerService?wsdl=1"/>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="CustomerSOAPServicePortBindingPolicy"/>
<binding xmlns:ns1="http://xml.he-arc.ch/srv/CustomerService/1.0" name="CustomerSOAPServicePortBinding" type="ns1:CustomerService">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#CustomerSOAPServicePortBindingPolicy"/>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="updCustomer">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="addCustomer">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="getCustomer">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="delCustomer">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="getCustomers">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="CustomerService">
<port name="CustomerSOAPServicePort" binding="tns:CustomerSOAPServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/TB-Service2/CustomerService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**Flow**

```
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/TB-Service2/CustomerService?wsdl" service="CustomerService" port="CustomerSOAPServicePort" serviceAddress="http://localhost:8080/TB-Service2/CustomerService" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="Xml_getCustomersResponse__To_JSON" transformationGraphPath="xml_getcustomersresponse__to_json.grf" doc:name="Xml_getCustomersResponse__To_JSON"/>
    <flow name="web-service-parkingFlow1" doc:name="web-service-parkingFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="getCustomers" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="getCustomers" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_getCustomersResponse__To_JSON" doc:name="Xml&lt;getCustomersResponse&gt; To JSON"/>
        <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to Mule software and web services. This is my first time I'm adding a soap web service in mule flow. I also follow mule examples (orderTshirt Flow). I don't know how I can generate a WSDL file for "order tshart". In the example they just set the WSDL location and didn't explain about this file. I'm wondering if you can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a namespace-manager: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML+Namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an CXF component  in your flow If yes then in proxy service change the payload from body(default) to envelope.

```
   <cxf:proxy-service doc:name="Proxy Service"
    wsdlLocation="wcs/wsdl/listInventory.wsdl" 
    namespace="http://www.example.com"
    payload="envelope" port="OrderServices" service="OrderServices" />
```